# How to get average salary for each experience level for each job title?

Tags: julia

I got the dataset like following:
[image]
I would like to get average salary for each experience level in each job title, I have tried:

```
 second=combine(groupby(new,:experience_level,),:salary_in_usd =>IMD.mean)
```

but then I realized if I do the leftjoin here it will be same salary for all experience level in different job title, my goal is to get a dataset where each experience level have average salary in each job title,does anyone knows how to do that? use Inmemorydataset package functions please.
Thanks

Comment: Next time please provide code that generates input data (even simplified). rather than a console  screenshot. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to groupby by both job title and experience level:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Statistics

julia> salaries = DataFrame(
           job_title = ["Data Analyst","Data Analyst","Data Analyst","Data Analyst","Data Scientist","Data Scientist","Data Scientist","Data Scientist","ML Specialist","ML Specialist","ML Specialist","ML Specialist"],
           salary_in_usd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
           work_year = [2020,2020,2022,2022,2020,2020,2022,2022,2020,2020,2022,2022],
           experience_level = ["EN","SE","EN","SE","EN","SE","EN","SE","EN","SE","EN","SE"]
       );

julia> groups = groupby(salaries,["job_title","experience_level"]);

julia> avg_salaries = combine(groups,  "salary_in_usd" => mean => "avg_salary")
6×3 DataFrame
 Row │ job_title       experience_level  avg_salary 
     │ String          String            Float64    
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Data Analyst    EN                       2.0
   2 │ Data Analyst    SE                       3.0
   3 │ Data Scientist  EN                       6.0
   4 │ Data Scientist  SE                       7.0
   5 │ ML Specialist   EN                      10.0
   6 │ ML Specialist   SE                      11.0

julia> avg_salary_nice = unstack(avg_salaries,"experience_level","avg_salary")
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ job_title       EN        SE       
     │ String          Float64?  Float64? 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Data Analyst         2.0       3.0
   2 │ Data Scientist       6.0       7.0
   3 │ ML Specialist       10.0      11.0
```

See also [my tutorial on Split-Apply-Combine](https://sylvaticus.github.io/SPMLJ/stable/02_-_JULIA2_-_Scientific_programming_with_Julia/0201_-_Wranging_data.html#The-Split-Apply-Combine-strategy) (with video on top of the page)

OT: how many job "names"....

Comment: worth noting that `Symbol`s can be also used in place of `String`s eg. ` groups = groupby(salaries,[:job_title,:experience_level])`